# Aspose.Word convert DOCX to HTML looses MERGEFIELD, IF conditions, headers and footer, table cell widths

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I'm trying to write a online document editor with TinyMCE 5 as editor and Aspose.Word v20.8 as converter.

But when I convert the DOCX to HTML5 with Aspose.Word, it is not rendering as expected in TinyMCE.
The HTML looses for example headers, footers, MergeFields, IF, TableStart:TableEnd sofar I can tell now.
I need this HTML has all the data because I need to convert it back to DOCX again.

Code to generate the HTML5 is:

```
var doc = new Document({Stream_Of_DOCX});
var options = new HtmlSaveOptions();
options.SaveFormat = SaveFormat.Html;
options.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
options.UpdateFields = true;
options.ExportRoundtripInformation = true;
options.ExportImagesAsBase64 = true;
options.ExportFontsAsBase64 = true;
options.ExportPageSetup = true;
options.ExportDocumentProperties = true;
options.ExportHeadersFootersMode = ExportHeadersFootersMode.PerSection;
options.HtmlVersion = HtmlVersion.Html5;

doc.Save($"{fileName}.html", options);
```

The code to convert the HTML5 back to DOCX is, were the model.Html is the TinyMCE textarea:

```
var doc = new Document();
var builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
builder.InsertHtml(model.Html);
doc.Save($"{fileName}.docx");
```

Can anybody help me to get this working with some code examples?
Or maybe has a better idear to accomplish the task.
The main idear is to be able to edit DOCX files online, without to have to download it and upload again with some windows service as client for example.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Words do preserve headers and footers upon saving to HTML if ExportRoundtripInformation option is enabled. In this case Aspose.Words writes header and footer content with special css attributes, which are understood by Aspose.Words:

```html
<div style="-aw-headerfooter-type:header-primary; clear:both">
    <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; line-height:normal">
        <span>header</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Also, Aspose.Words preserves some fields (PAGE, NUMPAGES, NOTEREF, REF, AUTOR and TITLE). For example, PAGE field is exported like the following:

```html
<span style="-aw-field-start:true"></span><span style="-aw-field-code:' PAGE   \\* MERGEFORMAT '"></span><span style="-aw-field-separator:true"></span><span>1</span><span style="-aw-field-end:true"></span>
```

Such content is recognized by Aspose.Words upon reading HTML and loaded into the model as field. I logged a request WORDSNET-21037 to preserve other types of fields too.

I am not familiar with TinyMCE, but I suspect that custom attributes used by Aspose.Words for roundtrip MS Word features are removed and that is why Header and Footer are not preserved in your case.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. 
When I convert DOCX to HTML with Aspose.Word I see in TinyMCE that the HTML contains this "-aw-headerfooter-type" text. So it isn't removed by TinyMCE. 
Whenever I save the TinyMCE-HTML back to the server, the whole HTML content is converted by Aspose.Word to DOCX again and it should be the same as the original DOCX I supose.

Comment: @Christiaan It depends on the complexity of the document you convert to HTML and back. Html format cannot preserve all Word document features, that is why such custom attributes are used. I tested a simple document with header/footer and few fields and after DOCX->HTML->DOCX roundtrip header, footer and supported fields are preserved.

Comment: Ok, then which settings are wrong in the above code? 
I have MERGEFIELD and IF code in my Word document and a image in the header and a pagenumber in the footer. And tables are not aligned as in the orginal.
Can you wrtie the code you are using to do the roundtrip?
Is it wrong to think that the input and output should be the same?
When I look at for example to DevExpress that has an nice RichEditor which works as expected. I thought maybe Aspose.Word can that too.

Comment: I used your code to convert to HTML and then open the resulting HTML using Aspose.Words again and saved it to DOCX. Header, footer, table and PAGE field are properly preserved in output DOCX document. As I mentioned MERGEFIELD and IF fields are not preserved upon DOCX->HTML-DOCX roundtrip and this is logged as a defect. Input and output documents really must look the same if input and output formats support the same set of features. HTML and DOCX do not. DevExpress demo really looks cool, but I am not sure they are using HTML or only HTML format as intermediate format for editing.